# Looking for a simple but effective firewall

Tags: linux-mint, firewall

I just freshly install a new machine running on `linuxmint-19.2-xfce-64bit`.

I set the Gufw to block all incoming and outgoing traffic but my system still receive an IP address! The software manager fetch result on query (unless this is local ??) but Firefox is at least blocked.

So how I can simply block everything? Also when a process try to make a connection, I want that I'm warned on screen, by a window, pop-up or similar notification?

[image: 1]]

Comment: Why don't you just unplug the ethernet cable if you want a non-connected machine ?

Comment: @binarym I'm looking for a reliable firewall. if you deny everything, you shouldn't even have a dhcp exchange. So after you can open one by one what you need. That how it should work.

Comment: From what address range did your IP address get assigned? DHCP scope or 169.254.x.x?

Comment: Does `gufw` have a built-in exception for DHCP traffic?

Comment: @roaima , no I get a correct IP for my subnet 192.168.... and not an apipa.
and it appear than gufw have few built-in exception, someone can confirm ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On Linux, the standard network stack forbids to send an IP packet with source IP 0.0.0.0 (probably since kernel 2.2). As this is required by the DHCP protocol, DHCP tools must bypass this limitation.

Thus DHCP clients rely on RAW sockets to craft this forbidden packet with source IP 0.0.0.0 and actually use them for the initial DHCP exchanges. Those packets are bypassing the network stack, including iptables.

Here are some related links quickly found:

[A Guide to Using Raw Sockets](https://opensourceforu.com/2015/03/a-guide-to-using-raw-sockets/)
[Red Hat Bugzilla – Bug 1269914 - can't firewall packets coming through raw sockets](https://bugzilla.redhat.com/show_bug.cgi?id=1269914)
[ISC - How DHCP uses raw sockets](https://kb.isc.org/docs/aa-00379)

Anyway it's possible to firewall this by using an Ethernet bridge, even if it's not needed for anything else. So you could choose to create a bridge interface and enslave your unique Ethernet interface in it (beware, Wireless Wifi interfaces usually don't work on a bridge without complex settings), and set the DHCP client to use the bridge's self interface rather than the original ethernet interface. The packets emitted by the DHCP client will then be switched, so subject to bridge firewalling using [`ebtables`](https://manpages.debian.org/ebtables/ebtables-legacy.8) (nftables could also be used instead):

```
ebtables -A OUTPUT -j DROP
```

same for received packets:

```
ebtables -A INPUT -j DROP
```

Or if you don't want to do this, you must go even lower, at the interface level, which is possible when using [`tc`](https://manpages.debian.org/iproute2/tc.8). Let's suppose your interface is called `eth0` (your picture is hard to read):

Add a classful *simple* qdisc to be able to attach filters:

```
tc qdisc add dev eth0 root handle 1: prio
```

Add a match all/drop all filter and action:

```
tc filter add dev eth0 parent 1: matchall action drop
```

Now nothing will be able to go out of the interface, but incoming packets can still be seen if needed.

(You can revert everything with `tc qdisc del dev eth0 root`)

Similarly you can block all incoming data:

```
tc qdisc add dev eth0 ingress
tc filter add dev eth0 ingress matchall action drop
```

(cancel with `tc qdisc del dev eth0 ingress`)

I can't tell it's simple, but the `tc` method achieves complete lockdown in 4 commands, and it won't need reconfiguring other network tools like NetworkManager, like would probably be needed with the use of a bridge (and it will also work on Wifi).

Comment: Since Linux kernel 5.16.x using *nftables* and netdev ingress + netdev egress is an alternative to tc.