# arptables not working with nmap

Tags: networking, firewall, ethernet, nftables, arp

I'm trying to implement a way to prevent network scans from my notebook. One of the things I want is to allow arp request to specific hosts, like my gateway.
I added some rules using arptables and they seem to work (at first)

```
arptables -A OUTPUT -d 192.168.1.30 -j DROP
arptables -A INPUT  -s 192.168.1.30 -j DROP
```

This is actually blocking arp requests to this host. If I run:

```
tcpdump -n port not 22 and host 192.168.1.38 (target host)
```

and run:

```
arp -d 192.168.1.30; ping -c 1 192.168.1.30; arp -n (notebook)
```

tcpdump shows no incoming packets on the target and arp -n on the notebook show (incomplete)

But if I run nmap -sS 192.168.1.30 on my notebook I get on the target host:

```
22:21:12.548519 ARP, Request who-has 192.168.1.30 tell 192.168.1.38, length 46
22:21:12.548655 ARP, Reply 192.168.1.30 is-at xx:xx:xx:xx:xx:xx, length 28
22:21:12.728499 ARP, Request who-has 192.168.1.30 tell 192.168.1.38, length 46
22:21:12.728538 ARP, Reply 192.168.1.30 is-at xx:xx:xx:xx:xx:xx, length 28
```

but an arp -n on the notebook still shows incomplete, but the nmap detects the host.
I also tried using **nftables** and **ebtables** with no success.

How can I prevent nmap to send arp request and finding the host?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'll complete OP's setup: address 192.168.1.38/24 on `eth0` and a gateway (not really needed) 192.168.1.1. If the setup uses Wifi rather than actual Ethernet, the first method (bridge) won't be available without additional efforts (probably easy if Access Point, very difficult to impossible if not AP).

---

- `nmap` uses a [packet socket](https://manpages.debian.org/manpages/packet.7) (type `AF_PACKET`) to craft ARP requests, rather than using the kernel's network stack dealing with ARP cache and resolution. `arping` behave similarly (and will be used instead to simplify examples).
- `tcpdump` *also* uses `AF_PACKET` to capture.
- By contrast even other special tools such as `ping`, when they merely use `AF_INET, SOCK_DGRAM, IPPROTO_IP` or `AF_INET, SOCK_RAW, IPPROTO_ICMP` rather than `AF_PACKET`,  will be filtered by `iptables`.

Their methods can be verified using `strace -e trace=%network` (as *root* user) on these commands.

As presented in *Packet flow in Netfilter and General Networking*:

[image: Packet flow in Netfilter and General Networking]

`AF_PACKET` happens before (at ingress) or after (at egress) most of Netfilter's subsystems, *ebtables* (bridge), *arptables* or *iptables* and their equivalent *nftables* tables: the firewall is bypassed. `tcpdump` (or `nmap`) is able to read incoming packets because it captures them before the firewall, `nmap` is able to send ARP packets because it injects them after the firewall.

So with a standard setup, any packet generated by `nmap` or any other tool using `AF_PACKET` can't be filtered with `arptables` (or `iptables`).

There are ways to overcome this.

### Old method: using a bridge and `ebtables`

It's bridging, thus in most cases not compatible with Wifi.

For *ebtables* (or *nftables* using `bridge` family) it's usually not a problem: when the ARP or IP packet that couldn't be filtered is turned into an Ethernet frame it re-enters the network stack at an other layer. Now it's within the network stack and will be affected by all the facilities there, including bridge firewall rules created with `ebtables` (or *nftables* with a `bridge` family). Using a bridge thus allows to overcome the firewall bypass.

Create a bridge, set `eth0` as bridge port and move the addresses and routes on `br0` (of course this should be done by reconfiguring the adequate network tool in use and/or not done remotely because of the temporary loss of connectivity):

```
ip link add name br0 up type bridge
ip link set dev eth0 master br0
ip addr flush dev eth0
ip addr add 192.168.1.38/24 brd + dev br0
ip route add default via 192.168.1.1 # not needed for this problem
```

Then transform the `arptables` rules into `ebtables` rules. They'll still use `INPUT` and `OUTPUT` because these are the chains between the routing stack and (for lack of better term) the bridge stack.

```
ebtables -A OUTPUT -p ARP --arp-ip-dst 192.168.1.30 -j DROP
ebtables -A INPUT -p ARP --arp-ip-src 192.168.1.30 -j DROP
```

One roughly equivalent *nftables* ruleset could be (to load with `nft -f somerulefile.nft`):

```
add table bridge t    # for idempotence
delete table bridge t # for idempotence

table bridge t {
    chain out {
        type filter hook output priority 0; policy accept;
        arp daddr ip 192.168.1.30 drop
    }

    chain in {
        type filter hook input priority 0; policy accept;
        arp saddr ip 192.168.1.30 drop
    }
}
```

(Additional filtering to limit the affected interface should probably be added.)

With one of these rules in place, running concurrently two `tcpdump`, one on `br0` one on `eth0` like this:

```
tcpdump -l -n -e -s0 -i br0 arp &
tcpdump -l -n -e -s0 -i eth0 arp &
```

will show emission on `br0` but not on `eth0` anymore: the ARP packet which couldn't be blocked when injected is effectively blocked by the bridge layer. If the rules are removed, both interfaces will show traffic. Likewise for the reverse test from remote: the packet will be captured on `eth0` but won't reach `br0`: blocked.

### New method: *nftables* with [`netdev` family](https://manpages.debian.org/nftables/nft.8#NETDEV_ADDRESS_FAMILY) and `egress` hook

**⚠**: requires Linux [kernel >= 5.16](https://kernelnewbies.org/Linux_5.16#Networking) which provides the `egress` hook, and [`nftables` >= 1.0.1](https://lwn.net/Articles/876497/) to use it. `ingress` has been available since kernel 4.2.

As there's no bridge involved, there's no change of network layout needed, and this will work the same for Ethernet or for Wifi.

In particular this [commit](https://git.kernel.org/pub/scm/linux/kernel/git/torvalds/linux.git/commit/?id=42df6e1d221dddc0f2acf2be37e68d553ad65f96) presents use cases:

> netfilter: Introduce egress hook
>
> Support classifying packets with netfilter on egress to satisfy user
> requirements such as:
>
> - outbound security policies for containers (Laura)
> - filtering and mangling intra-node Direct Server Return (DSR) traffic   on a load balancer (Laura)
> - **filtering locally generated traffic coming in through AF_PACKET, such as local ARP traffic** generated for clustering purposes or DHCP
>   (Laura; the AF_PACKET plumbing is contained in a follow-up commit)
>
> [...]

*nftables* provides access to additional Netfilter hooks (not described in previous schematic) in the `netdev` family working at the interface level: `ingress` and `egress`. These hooks are near `AF_PACKET` for ingress and egress (staying fuzzy because implementations details with regard to ingress/egress and capture/injection have some subtleties): `egress` is able to affect packets injected at `AF_PACKET`.

Base chains in `netdev` family tables must be linked to (an) interface(s). Using OP's initial setup, the previous *nftables* ruleset can be rewritten using the `netdev` family's syntax like this:

```
add table netdev t    # for idempotence
delete table netdev t # for idempotence

table netdev t {
    chain out {
        type filter hook egress device eth0 priority 0; policy accept;
        arp daddr ip 192.168.1.30 drop
    }

    chain in {
        type filter hook ingress device eth0 priority 0; policy accept;
        arp saddr ip 192.168.1.30 drop
    }
}
```

`tcpdump` won't capture any injected ARP at egress: they were dropped before. Capture at ingress still happens first: tools relying on `AF_PACKET` (starting with `tcpdump`) can still capture them (but the firewall will drop them right after).

---

Misc: There's also `tc` which is able to filter `AF_PACKET` sockets (if the tool doesn't use the option [`PACKET_QDISC_BYPASS`](https://manpages.debian.org/manpages/packet.7#PACKET_QDISC_BYPASS)). `tc` is more difficult to handle. Here's a [Q/A with an answer of mine](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/556827/looking-for-a-simple-but-effective-firewall/556918#556918) (at the time I wrote it my understanding and overall explanation was less acurate) having a simple example without filter.

[eBPF](https://docs.kernel.org/bpf/) using [XDP](https://www.kernel.org/doc/html/latest/networking/af_xdp.html) has also access to such filtering.

Comment: Note: when the packet is dropped at injection (new method) (rather than later in old method), nmap will be made aware of it (eg: `WARNING: eth_send of ARP packet returned -1 rather than expected 42 (errno=105: No buffer space available)`). There would be a method still relying on egress to prevent it noticing. If needed just ask. But anyway the person with root access can always figure out what is going on given enough effort.